# Change scroll behavior of mouse from vertical to horizontal

Tags: applescript, mouse

Is a possible to use AppleScript to switch the scroll wheel of the mouse from up/down to left/right?

At first I searched and found this:

```
tell application "System Events"
   key down shift
end tell
```

and

```
tell application "System Events"
   key up shift
end tell
```

but the thing is that it interrupts with the application I'm using currently and every keystroke I type is obviously typed with a shift modifier key.

I will be very grateful for any tip to work around this.

PS. If that matters, actually I use a Kensington Trackball instead of a regular mouse and want to switch between the behavior (vertical/horizontal ) when scrolling a ball.

Comment: Can't you just turn the trackball by 90 degrees?

Comment: When you're scrolling you're unlikely to be typing simultaneously. What's wrong with just holding Shift?

Comment: @Tetsujin I want to use that with Keyboard Maestro and toggle between vertical/horizontal scrolling at specific conditions (like focused window title etc.).
The cause is that on one window I want to scroll up/down and on the other I want left/right.
Reason why holding shift is irritating is that there are times when I have to use it with other modifier keys, and there's always need to remember to hold down shift.